# How to display several d3 reusable charts in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I'm trying to draw D3 reusable charts (https://github.com/prcweb/d3-radialbar) in the centroid of several regions (also drawn with D3) of a leaflet map (followed this tutorial: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/). When drawing the charts outside the leaflet pane, it works fine, but when appending them to my g element (which i use for all svgs in my map) they seem to disappear.

As of right now, I have drawn simple circles where I want my charts to display, and these show up just fine. The problem seems to happen when adding the graphs inside the regions. This is the result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgawC.jpg) and code when treating the graphs exactly the same as circles in the centroids of the regions. As you can see, the circles show up, but not the graphs at all. What am I missing here?

```
    var mymap = new L.map('mymap', {
        maxZoom: 10,
        maxZoom: 10,
        minZoom: 5,
        maxBounds: [
            //south west bounds
            [59, 0],
            //north east bounds
            [74, 37]
        ],
        maxBoundsViscosity: 1,
    }).setView([68.8, 20.7], 6);




    //Fetching map from internet, change this to switch whole background map
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(mymap);



     //Adding SVG on top
    var svg = d3.select(mymap.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
        g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide")

    d3.json("subunits.json", function(error, collection) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint}),
          path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

        var feature = g.selectAll("path")
              .data(collection.features)
            .enter().append("path")
              .attr('style', 'z-index:9999');

        var circles = g.selectAll("circle")
              .data(collection.features)
            .enter().append("circle")
              //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
              .attr("r", 15) //function(d) {return Math.floor(Math.random()*30);})
              .attr('style', 'z-index:9999');

        //-----------------Radial bar chart init and functions-------------------------------------------------
        var data = [];
        var keys = ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

        function initData() {
            data = [{data: {}}];
            for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)
                data[0].data[keys[i]] = Math.random() * 10;
        };
        var chart = radialBarChart()
            .barHeight(25)
            .reverseLayerOrder(true)
            //.capitalizeLabels(true)
            .barColors(['#e6194b', '#f58231', '#ffe119', '#bcf60c', '#3cb44b', '#46f0f0', '#4363d8', '#911eb4', 'f032e6'])
            .domain([0,10])
            .tickValues([])
            .tickCircleValues([]);

        initData();

        var charts = g.selectAll("chart")
              .data(collection.features)
            .enter().append("chart")
              .datum(data)
              .attr('style', 'z-index:9999')
              .call(chart);




        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       

        mymap.on("moveend", reset);
        reset();

        // Reposition the SVG to cover the features.
        function reset() {
            var bounds = path.bounds(collection),
                topLeft = bounds[0],
                bottomRight = bounds[1];




            circles .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + 
                    path.centroid(d) + ")";

                });

            charts  .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + 
                    path.centroid(d) + ")";

                });



            svg     .attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
                    .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
                    .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
                    .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

            g       .attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");

            feature.attr("d", path);
            circles.attr("d", path);
            charts.attr("d", path);

        }

        // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
        function projectPoint(x, y) {
            var point = mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
            this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
        }


    });

    function applyLatLngToLayer(d) {
        var y = d.geometry.coordinates[1];
        var x = d.geometry.coordinates[0];
        return mymap.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
    }
```

Edit:
The contents of subunits.json (https://jsonblob.com/69f458e1-2d52-11e9-ae1f-75a64cc80f0a) includes the shape (and some other data) for the different communes in the area of Norway i'm trying to display data for. The charts should go in the centroid of these communes.

Comment: A working example (e.g. codepen, jsfiddle) would be helpful. What is the content of `subunits.json`?